# how to call synchronise call in sqlite phonegap (check duplicate item before insert )

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite, cordova

I need to check duplicate columns(item) before inserting the data in table .But it is asynchronise call .so it is not working .I need to call synchronise call  so that i can get value **true and false**

Then check for insert value or not.

```
function validationField() {
          db.transaction(getallTableCntend, errorCB);
        }


        function getallTableCntend(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], queryexcecute, errorCB);
        }
        function queryexcecute(tx, result) {
            var len = result.rows.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              if(result.rows.item(i).CaseName ==$('.caseName_h').val()){
                alert("Folder is already Exit.");
                isvalid=false;
                Break;
                return;;
              }


            }
           }

    I am calling this like this.
    $(document).on('click', '#AddButton', function() {
         isvalid = validationField();
        if (isvalid) {
                insertData();
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);



        }
    });
```

---

May i create table Like that..
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');
 and Use Like  That...

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE  INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');
```

----------------------------------------------Do like that--------------

```
function checkExitingFolderName(){
db.transaction(getallTableCntend, errorCB);
}

function getallTableCntend(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName ='+$('.caseName_h').val(), [], queryexcecute, errorCB);
}
function queryexcecute(tx, result) {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    alert("hi"+length);
if(len>0){
alert("Folder")
}
else{
insertData();
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to `insertData` into the `queryexcecute` function.

Please note that you do not need to read the entire table yourself; just execute this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName = ?
```

and check whether you get some record back.

Alternatively, ensure you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `CaseName` column, and unconditionally execute an [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement.